# Insanely High Fee

Tags: bitcoin-core

Hello Programming Friends,

Can any experts quickly tell me how to disable the insanely high fee feature or raise it so it will not cause any warnings/errors in the future,
see example below

[image]

[image]

Solved. The error was coming from the fee being in satoshis, but was being calculated in whole coins instead, causing a massive fee. 1 Coin = 100,000,000 satoshis

Comment: What software are you using?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to disable it without recompiling from source after removing the check from `validation.cpp`.

Additionally, even after you do that, most nodes on the network will still fail to relay your transaction, since they all still have the check enabled.

If you need to pay that high a fee, you are likely doing something wrong.

Comment: Thank you again for so much help, do you have offsite chat details to discuss further? I added another image to the post that has been customized, but not solved the issue